# Method in class instance keeps old Activity references after Activity with Fragments is recreated (upon device orientation change)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

Today I struggled with an issue which I would like to share with you, and get your opinion on how to best solve this in my app.

**Context:** 
What I want is to have a layout with an ActionBar and Fragments. For the Fragments I use the default code by Android Studio using a ViewPager with SectionsPagerAdapter which fills with PlaceholderFragments. The different Fragments have one XML, and differ by some TextViews that I alter in the onViewCreated() override of the PlaceholderFragments class based on the tab postition. Also, I want the Fragments to have a slightly different layout in landscape mode, so I added a fragment_activity.xml to the res/layout-land/ directory.
In this Activity I made a class, and in this class I have a method called updateControlButtons():

```
public class SomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
(...)
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hangboard);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    Log.i("onCreate", actionBar.toString());
    (...)
  }

    private class SomeClass {
       public void updateControlButtons() {
       (...)

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                    actionBar.hide();
                    Log.i("updateControlButtons", actionBar.toString());
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON); // KeepScreenOn off
                    (...)
                }
          }
       (...)
       }
    (.....)
  }
```

To handle the orientation changes of the device, I have to reinitialize several TextViews to the current tab, and also to the current state of what was going on on the screen (which is based on fields stored in SomeClass). For that I override the onViewCreated() method as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //default code:
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState); //this does not really do something

        int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER); 
        Log.i("TEST onViewCreated position", Integer.toString(position));

        switch (position) {
            // no 0
            case 1: //BEGINNER
                someTextView.setText("0:05");
                break;
            (...)
        }

        // Reload the View IDs into the SomeClass if it is the current view created and SomeClass exists!
        if (SomeClass != null && SomeClass.timerTab == position) { 
             updateCurrentViewIDs(); 
        } // timerTab contains the Tab number on which the user started a timer, these values have to be restored
```

With updateCurrentViewIDs a method of the Activity:

```
private static void updateCurrentViewIDs() {
    // for device reorientation

    Log.i("updateCurrentViewIDs", "View re-initialised");
    View mView = mViewPager.findViewWithTag(SomeClass.timerTab); // the View that was playing

    SomeClass.mView = mView;

    // findIDs for current tab
    SomeClass.tvTimer = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
    SomeClass.tvTimerRemaining = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimerRemaining);
    SomeClass.tvTimerTotal = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimerTotal);
    (..)

    //update controls
    SomeClass.updateControlButtons();
```

**Correct:** The TextView IDs get properly updated to the new View that was initialized  by the Fragment recreation (due to the Activity recreation), and can be used by the SomeClass which is still running.

**Problem:**
When I do not update the ID of something that wasn't even stored inside the SomeClass, the ID of the *old (and removed)* reference in the Fragment is still used by SomeClass! For example, the SomeClass.updateControlButtons() called by the new Fragment (in onViewCreated() ) still gets the *old* ID for the ActionBar in SomeClass.updateControlButtons() ! This can be seen in the logcat:

```
I/onCreate﹕ android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar@420f7570
I/TEST onViewCreated position﹕ 1
(..)
I/SomeClass.start()﹕ called
I/updateControlButtons﹕ android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar@420f7570
(..)
(NOW DEVICE IS ORIENTED TO LANDSCAPE)
I/onCreate﹕ android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar@421592d0
I/TEST onViewCreated position﹕ 1
I/updateCurrentViewIDs﹕ View re-initialised
I/updateControlButtons﹕ android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar@420f7570
```

Of course when the SomeClass instance is closed, and new instance is created, the ActionBar is referenced correct again.

**Solution**: Of course I could simply store the ActionBar in the onCreate method globally and put it as a field in the SomeClass inside the updateCurrentViewIDs() method. Then I could replace getSupportActionBar with that updated field. I would also have to do that for the Window, to have a correct call to:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

By the way, using the setRetainInstance(true) call does not work for me, as I actually want to change the layout in landscape mode.

**Question**: I do not like this way, it feels as if I should update way too much upon a simple orientation change of the device. Something that in my opinion should (and is) not even stored in the SomeClass?! Could this not be solved in an easier or more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer by looking more into [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Also, according to the [documentation on Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

*Your application should be able to restart at any time without loss of user data or state in order to handle events such as configuration changes or when the user receives an incoming phone call and then returns to your application much later after your application process may have been destroyed. To learn how you can restore your activity state, read about the Activity lifecycle.*

Therefore I will now look into how to use the Bundle to save and restore information upon Activity recreation.

Moreover, I probably need to pause my current SomeClass instance, and create a new one upon Activity restore. This is however rather tricky, as I have a for loop running inside the SomeClass, so no clues yet how to solve that... Still, I think it is a bit weird that the getSupportActionBar() call inside the method inside the SomeClass refers to the last (and destroyed) Activity rather then the newly created Activity, but this is how it is compiled apparently?

**Update**
I finally chose to keep track of the current ActionBar and Window by storing these in Activity class wide static variables. I update these variables upon Recreation by adding these lines in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    (..)
    storedActionBar = actionBar; //PETER: added to be able to access the new ActionBar upon Activiy Recreate (e.g. orientation change)
    storedWindow = getWindow(); // for the KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag
```

Comment: Apparently I could also make use of Loaders: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html